# character counting not works for the dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using charcount.js  to count the number of characters entered in the textarea..

```
    <textarea class="counter" rows="3"></textarea>
```

in jquery i called it as

```
    $('.counter').charCount();
```

it works for me...when i created the textarea in the javascript dynamically  it does not works

```
    var txtar=document.createElement("textarea");
    txtar.setAttribute("maxlength","140");
    txtar.setAttribute("class","counter");
    ad.appendChild(txtar);
```

the textarea correctly added into the document but the charcount function not works .....

how can i resolve this

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to count the characters while the user enters text in the textarea? To produce a message like: x characters used|left?

Comment: ya i have to display the remaining characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling `charCount()` *after* the element has been appended to the DOM? You should be.

Comment: ya you are right ...early i called the function on the creation of DOM elements but not tried after appending thanks for you to spend your time to answer me